# What happens if we split by a delimiter yet have multiple of those delimiters in a row?

Tags: python

Say I have a string `"word1 word2 word3 word4 etc"`, however instead of there being only one space between the words, the amount of spaces is random greater than 1. How does `split(" ")` work in such cases?

Comment: Have you tried it? This is something that is very easy to test for yourself. You can also very easily [look it up in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split).

Comment: I just thought it would be a useful question to ask, unless someone has already asked it.

Comment: @user3251142: did you search first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str.split(" ")` gives you multiple empty values. Use `str.split(None)` or just `str.split()` instead; it'll collapse arbitrary-width whitespace into one split position:

```
>>> 'demo  with   multiple    spaces'.split(' ')
['demo', '', 'with', '', '', 'multiple', '', '', '', 'spaces']
>>> 'demo  with   multiple    spaces'.split()
['demo', 'with', 'multiple', 'spaces']
```

The `None` or no argument version also removes leading and trailing whitespace, including tabs and newlines:

```
>>> '\tdemo with some leading  \t and trailing whitespace\n'.split()
['demo', 'with', 'some', 'leading', 'and', 'trailing', 'whitespace']
```

while `str.split(' ')` splits *only* on spaces:

```
>>> '\tdemo with some leading  \t and trailing whitespace\n'.split(' ')
['\tdemo', 'with', 'some', 'leading', '', '\t', 'and', 'trailing', 'whitespace\n']
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is an arbitrary amount of whitespace between each one, `split()` without arguments will work just fine:

```
>>> 'foo bar  baz   quz'.split()
['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux']
```

`split()` by defaults to all whitespace as the delimiter. If you specify a single space `' '`, that is all it will split on and you will get empty strings as a result.